# sonar-maven-plugin 3.7.0.1746

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I am getting below error while using the plugin (sonar-maven-plugin 3.7.0.1746):

ERROR:
Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project kcc-xbu-saprfc-services-sys-api: Unexpected internal error near index 1

I have added below in pom.xml file in respective sections:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.7.0.1746</version>
</plugin>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.7.0.1746</version>
</dependency>

<repository>
<id>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</id>
<name>sonar-maven-plugin</name>
<url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonarsource.scanner.maven/sonar-maven-plugin</url>
<layout>default</layout>
</repository>

<pluginRepository>
<id>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</id>
<name>sonar-maven-plugin</name>
<layout>default</layout>
<url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonarsource.scanner.maven/sonar-maven-plugin</url>
<snapshots>
<enabled>false</enabled>
</snapshots>
</pluginRepository>
```

Versions currently being used:

1. SonarQube version: 7.9.1
2. MULE_EE with version 4.2.2
3. JDK: 1.8.0_251 (mixed mode)
4. Maven Version      : 3.173.0

However maven is getting executed from "C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin\mvn.cmd".
I am executing the build using azure pipeline.

Please let me know how to resolve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Run with `-X` flag to see debug output.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to submit your code for SonarQube platform, normally the pom file doesn't need to have those dependencies, instead of it you can decouple that in changing the settings.xml of the maven (if you have a dedicated server, it should be inside .m2 folder for Windows).

Maven's settings.xml should have this profile:

```
<profile> 
   <id>sonar</id> 
   <activation>
       <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
       <properties>
          <sonar.login>*your-user-here*</sonar.login>
          <sonar.password>*your-pwd-here*</sonar.password>
          <sonar.host.url>*url-of-your-sonar-platform*</sonar.host.url>
       </properties>
   </activation>
<profile>
```

After that, you can setup you pipeline to run the following command for your project:

mvn sonar:sonar

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Eduardo Souza, I do have a dedicated sonar server and have the above entries in settings.xml on the agent machine.
I am using the maven task in azure pipeline and selecting the option (Run SonarQube Analysis), if I un-select this option and include the goal sonar:sonar, it still reports the same error posted above, please help.

Comment: instead of just running the goal sonar:sonar, please ensure you are running the goal "install". your complete maven command should be: mvn clean install sonar:sonar

Comment: I had earlier 'clean deploy sonar:sonar', changed it to 'clean install sonar:sonar', still same error. Changed java from 1.8 to 11.0.8, this did not help.

Comment: @J Fabian Meier, i included -Xdebug in mvn goal, I could see the sonar-maven-plugin 3.7.0.1746.jar getting downloaded and available on the agent machine's .m2/repository location. However could not find any other info related to the issue. Let me know if I need to search for any specific string from the debug log.